# How to ensure the matching between the result of applying a command and the result of applying an event

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

What certainty do we have with Event Sourcing that the state `Sx` of the aggregate after executing a command `Cx` will be the same when we populate the aggregate using all the events including the one generated by `Cx`.

[image: Event sourcing]

For example:

1. Command `Cx` arrives and it affects the aggregate `w`
2. We query for all events (`E1, E2..Ex-1`) associated to aggregate `w` and build its state to that point, obtaining `Sx-1`
3. We apply `Cx` to `Sx-1`, we obtain `Sx` and issue an event `Ex` that will be stored

How do I know that `Sx` generated by the command is equivalent to `Sx` generated by the events `E1, E2..Ex`.
Given that the building of the aggregate from the events is a different code than the one that processed the command there could be a mismatch between both aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

> We apply Cx to Sx-1, we obtain Sx and issue an event Ex that will be stored

That is not exactly right.

When handling a command, the application service calls a method of the aggregate:

```
var aggregate = store.Load<MyAggregate>(cmd.Id);
aggregate.DoWorkWhatever(cmd.OneField, cmd.TwoField);
```

The aggregate method won't just change the state, it will produce an event:

```
public void DoWorkWhatever(int one, string two) {
    Apply(new DidWorkWhatever { One = one, Two = two });
}
```

The `Apply` method calls some part of the aggregate to change its state:

```
When<DidWorkWhatever>((state, x) => { state.One = x.One, state.Two = x.Two });
```

In the end, you get the aggregate with the updated state *and* an event that triggered the state transition. So, the application service can persist the aggregate state by committing new events.

Maybe [examples from my book](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Domain-Driven-Design-with-.NET-Core/blob/master/Chapter11/in-database/Marketplace/ClassifiedAd/ClassifiedAdsApplicationService.cs#L23) can help.

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer is that `Sx` is computed by applying `Ex` to `Sx-1`

```
Sx-1 <- [E1..Ex-1]
Ex <- (Cx, Sx-1)
Sx <- (Sx-1, Ex) === ([E1..Ex-1], Ex) === ([E1..Ex])
```

> So the event has not really occurred. Don't you find that odd? It's an event that is not an event.

No, I don't find it odd.

Partly, that's because "events" in event sourcing are just ledger entries -- they are *bookkeeping*.  A sequence of little messages written by our previous selves so that our next self will know how to resume our work.

Comment: Let me clarify, just to see if I understand it correctly. After receiving `Cx` I generate `Ex` before applying it to `Sx-1`. So the event has not really occurred. Don't you find that odd? It's an event that is not an event.